# Rails determine if association is has_one or has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, has-one

Wondering if there is an easy way to determine dynamically if a model's association is a "`has_one`" or "`has_many`" relationship (i.e. is this an association to one object or many).

I'm using MongoMapper, so I am able to check if a class `klass` has an associated model `assoc` with a one or many relationship via

```
klass.associations[:assoc].is_a? MongoMapper::Plugins::Associations::OneAssociation
klass.associations[:assoc].is_a? MongoMapper::Plugins::Associations::ManyAssociation
```

but this seems rather clunky, and isn't generic (i.e. won't work for `ActiveRecord` associations as well). I'd also like to avoid loading any objects, so I'm pretty sure that `instance.assoc.is_a? Array` is out too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ever figure this one out? I just came to find the same thing, but just for `ActiveRecord`

Answer (score 12):

UPDATE: So, I happened upon the Reflections Class methods http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html

You can get all the `has_many`, `belongs_to`, etc. with `reflect_on_all_associations` method. It's all in there. Or you can put in an association into `reflect_on_association` and it will tell you if it is a `has_many`, `has_one`, etc. Specifically:

```
Model.reflect_on_association(:assoc).macro
```

This should be sufficient for all cases. It doesn't actually solve the problem I'm currently working on, but it should solve this.

Comment: It's not perfect, but it can work depending on your class names. Consider a class `User` which `has_one` of another class named `UserAttributes`. Unfortunately you'd access this via `user.user_attributes` which returns false to the `respond_to?(assoc_name.singularize)` call. You might argue (and you'd probably be correct) that you should rename this class `UserAttributeSet` or something similar, in which case `singularize` would work, but there's no guarantee that you'll get the association type correct just by whether the instance name is singular or plural.

Comment: Well, having a pluralized model name would go against Rails naming convention (http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7), so you should never have a model UserAttributes. It should always be UserAttribute. So singular or plural should reflect a has_one or has_many relationship. Any other concerns should be handled in whatever logic gets the input to begin with.

Comment: Indeed you're right - here's the better way to demonstrate that this doesn't cover every case: Consider the model `Fish` where the association name `"fish"` is uncountable. This means that the word "fish" is both the singular and plural form of the noun (i.e. `"fish".singularize == "fish".pluralize`), so via this means you don't know whether a model `has_one :fish` or `has_many :fish`.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a pretty unique case. You have that and deer and I can't even think of another example off the top of my head. And as a rule of thumb I wouldn't name a table with an irregular word that is the same singular or plural unless I absolutely had to just to avoid edge cases.